# Verify signature of Private key by Public key between Sender and Receiver in PHP

Tags: php, signature, phpseclib, verify

I create a Signature() function for the sender to sign his/her private key and then return the $signature

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

public function Signature(Request $request)
{
  $agent_code = $request->agent_code;
  $private_key = $request->private_key;
  $private_passphrase = $request->private_passphrase;

  $string = $agent_code;

  $private_key = File::get($private_key);

  $rsa = new RSA();
  $rsa->setPassword($private_passphrase);
  $rsa->loadKey($private_key); // private key

  $signature = base64_encode($rsa->sign($string));
  return $signature;
}
```

After that, the $signature is passed to Verify() function for the receiver to verify the signature using his/her public key

```
 public function Verify(Request $request)
 {
  $agent_code = $request->agent_code;
  $public_key = $request->public_key;
  $signature = $request->signature;

  $string = $agent_code;

  $public_key = File::get($public_key);

  $rsa = new RSA();
  $rsa->loadKey($public_key); // public key
  echo $rsa->verify($string, base64_decode($signature)) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';

}
```

Then, I test both function on Postman
Photo 1 - 3 is for the Signature() function
Photo 4 - 6 is for the Verify() function

Photo 1 : This url will call the Signature() function. The agent_code and private_passphrase param is filled. agent_code  is the string to be signed by private key whereas private_passphrase  is the passphrase for the private key.
[image]

Photo 2 : The private key is attached in body form as file format
[image]

Photo 3 : The $signature is returned
[image]

Photo 4 : This url will call the Verify() function. The agent_code and signature param is filled. the signature is copied from Signature() function that used to verified by the public key
[image]

Photo 5 : The public key is attached in body form as file format
[image]

Photo 6 : `Invalid signature` error
[image]

I have no idea why it return `Invalid Signature`, because if I write the signature and verify code in one function, it will echo 'verified' for me. The key pairs is correct and the $signature is copied correctly.

All the guidance and correction is appreciated.

Comment: I believe that you are using `Base64` encoding rather than `Base64URL` encoding. The former uses `+` and `/` while the latter uses `-` and `_` to allow using Base64-encoded values as query parameters in URLs.

Comment: Thanks IVO GELOV, now the Verify() function showing "verified". Appreciate your answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am converting my comment into an answer.

I believe that your issue is caused by the `+` signs in the query parameter(s) - they are being recognized as URL-encoded spaces. If you were using POST instead of GET there would not be any issue.

In order to avoid the problem with URL-encoding caused by the usual Base64 encoding my advice is to use [Base64URL](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url) encoding. It uses `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/` compared to the normal Base64 encoding.